Localhost:Port has been blocked by CORS policy
I'm receiving the following, though I've configured CORS in my middleware:

XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/api/check-admin' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CorsMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request);

        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200');
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Request-With');
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');

        if ($request->getMethod() === "OPTIONS") {
            return response('', 200)->withHeaders([
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => 'http://localhost:4200',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => 'Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Request-With',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => 'true',
            ]);
        }

        return $response;
    }
}


    'paths' => ['api/*','sanctum/csrf-cookie'],
    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
    'exposed_headers' => [],
    'max_age' => 0,
    'supports_credentials' => false,

but still the above error pops up. any suggestions?
I tried event add it manually to the index.php file. but still didn't work. is there any way to resolve this?
